# How to explicitly provide AWS credentials for Amazon Athena Service Client object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, credentials

The Amazon documentation says to use:

```
AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(
  "your_access_key_id",
  "your_secret_access_key");

S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
            .build();
```

But that's for the S3Client, when I try to use the same structure for my AthenaClient my app won't even run and it fails to initialize.

For my application I'm grabbing the credentials from a repo with a configuration file for this app.

```
static @Value("${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}") String amazonAccessId;

static @Value("${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}") String amazonSecretKey;

AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(
                "your_access_key_id",
                "your_secret_access_key");
        

AthenaClient athenaClient = AthenaClient.builder()
                .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
                .build();
```

I want to provide the credentials this way so that when I push the code from my local machine the code still functions, instead of relying on my environment variables. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, because the documentation does not.

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: "Please tell me what I'm doing wrong" You need to first tell us what exactly isn't working. Please provide details of any error or unexpected behavior you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

Understand how credentials work when using the **AWS SDK for Java V2** SDK. You can read about them in the AWS Java V2 Developer Guide here:

[Using credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html)

Specifically, read about the Credential retrieval order in that doc topic.

As far as what service you are using, it does not matter. An S3 Service Client works the same way as other Java Service clients in terms of handling creds.

The topic linked about describes this way to handle creds. As described in this topic, you can use the shared credentials and config files:

**The SDK uses the ProfileCredentialsProvider to load credentials from the [default] credentials profile in the shared credentials and config files.**

You can create a file named **credentials** - as shown here:

[image]

In that file - specify your keys:

[default]
aws_access_key_id=Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key=Kxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Then you can use this code to create a service client:

```
  AthenaClient athenaClient = AthenaClient.builder()
            .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
            .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
            .build();
```

And also - ensure you are using the correct POM in your Java project that uses Amazon Athena. See:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/athena